# Uncaught TypeError: tasks.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am getting an error tasks.map is not a function  i cant seem to find the problem. the problem might be the way i am setting the state or accessing the API but i cant find the problem
here is the code:

```
const Tasks = () => {

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState("");

  const [task, setTask] = useState("");
  const [importance, setImportance] = useState("Moderate");

  const TaskData = {
    'task' : task,
    'importance' : importance
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getTasks()
    console.log(tasks)
  }, []);
 
  
  let getTasks = async ()  => {
    let response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/list_task/`)
    let result = await response.json()

    setTasks(result)
    
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    createTask()
  }


  const createTask = (e) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/list_create/`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(TaskData)
    }).then(() => {
        setTask("")
    })
  }

  return (

    <div className="row justify-content-between">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="col-md-4  mt-5">
        <label  className="form-label ">Task</label>
        <input required onChange={(e) => setTask(e.target.value)} value= {task} className="form-control"  />

        <label className="form-label mt-5">Importance</label>
        <select onChange={(e) => setImportance(e.target.value)} className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
          <option selected hidden disabled value="null">Select The Importance Of This Task</option>
          <option value="Very Important">Very Important</option>
          <option value="Important">Important</option>
          <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
          <option value="Not Important">Not Important</option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit" className="mt-3 btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </button>

      </form>
      <div>

        {tasks.map((task, index) => (
 
          <ListItem key={index} task={task} />

        ))}

      </div>

      
    </div>
    
  ) 
};

export default Tasks;
```

here is the code to ListItem mentioned in the code above:

```
const ListItem = (task) => {

  return <div>
          <div className="col-md-6 text-center mt-5">

                <div className="card shadow-lg mt-5">
                    <div className="card-body">
                    <p className="card-title">{task.importance}</p>
                    <h3 className="card-text">{task.task}</h3>
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>;
        </div>;
        };

export default ListItem;
```

any help will appreciated thanks for your time and help

Comment: `listTasks.map` does not appaer in the provided code

Comment: On first render, Tasks will be empty/null, not an array. Only after useEffect runs will it be an array. Also you init the state with an empty string not an empty array. Always check for null in your components that take props to map like this. ` tasks && {tasks.map((task, index) => (`

Comment: I think the problem might be with the way you are initializing your state... Try useState([]) instead of useState("")

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum my bad i changed listTasks to tasks

Comment: Clarifying my comment: If you init the state with an empty array, it will be empty until the effect puts values in it.

Comment: @SiddharthSeth i add [] now its shows Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, task, importance, createdAt}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Try it without the extra parens?  `{tasks.map((task, index) => <ListItem key={index} task={task} /> )}`

Answer (score 0):

you're getting this error probably because task is actually empty because it is later set asynchronously in useEffect. Please use below code in order to check that task is not null.

```
{tasks.length>0 ? tasks.map((task, index) => (
 
          <ListItem key={index} task={task} />

        )) : null}
```

OR

```
{tasks?.map((task, index) => (
 
          <ListItem key={index} task={task} />

        ))}
```